# XCode6 beta UITextField with secureTextEntry doesn't take input

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6

I am validating my code against iOS 8 using XCode 6 beta (6A280e) and iPhone Simulator (Ver. 8.0 550)

I have a `UITextField` set as below:

```
self.myPasswordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES
```

so it can take password and show dots.

With this property, the UITextField doesn't take my input at all. I found I cannot type in anything with this property set to YES. Without this property it works OK.

I am wondering if this is a known bug? or does iOS 8 deprecated this property?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug in the simulator. Test on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with the resizable sim, and there should be a release note about it.  Feel free to file dupes...